# Best method of encrypting local data on iPhone application

Tags: ios, encryption

I have an application that stores data locally on the iPhone. 
I want to encrypt data so i am confused which method should i use.
I have used Core Data framework in application.

NSFileManager (NSFileProtectionKey), CoreData (NSFileProtectionKey), NSData (NSDataWritingOptions) are the options or is there some other method as well. 
Please suggest me something

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Keychain Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html).

But you need to now that to encrypt the data you need a private key or a passphrase.
I would then say, encryption make only sense, when the user needs to authenticate when using your application. Then you could encrypt the data with the entered password.
Here you could AES256 encrypt data with the a PBKDF2 like function for generating a encryption key (thanks to [Robert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/150978/robert)).
But providing a code sample would go to far. Read in yourself! :)

But also know: since iOS 4 the "disk" space is already encrypted with the Device PIN!

Comment: Never use a password as a key! Only derive a key from a password using a standardized key derivation function like PBKDF2.